# Crash: collection view layout: <MyLayout>) was deallocated while an update was in flight

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm getting the following crash when I navigate back off of my UICollectionViewController.

```
Crash: collection view layout: <MyLayout>) was deallocated while an update was in flight
```

It doesn't happen every time. It's more of a 1 in 10 kind of problem.

Has anyone seen this crash before and has anyone advice on how to debug it?

Comment: Also had the same crash but only with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout on tvOS. It often happens when I dismiss the view where there is a collectionView -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem as my code was reloading a cell in loop and it was calling the below method at continuously.

Just check your code if the below method is called when you pop or dismiss your viewController and correct it.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

That might help you to solve the bug